# eclipse workspace synchronization via dropbox - move the .metadata folder

Tags: java, eclipse, dropbox

I'm a student and have to work with Java and Eclipse. As we have teamprojects i have to sync my workspace with other students. The only problem i have is a folder called .metadata, right above my workspacefolder. Is there any possibility to change the path of this folder so that it won't be synced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sync your project folder instead of the whole workspace.

If you want to share multiple projects you can put them in a sub-folder of your workspace and share only this sub-folder.

BTW, I recommend you using a real SCM like GIT or SVN that give you opportunity to ignore some file/directory.

Comment: Hi, i did not know that the project does not have to be in the workspace folder. I will put the projects in the syncing folder - the .metadata folder will not be synched anymore. Thank you! I would use SVN - but i am a student and unfortunately i have not enough money to buy a server where i can run an svn server.

Comment: You can get free SVN or GIT hosting if giving public access to your code is not an issue. take a look at github.com !